# Reference Assemblies in .Net6.0 on multiple Versions

Tags: .net, plugins, json.net, .net-assembly, .net-6.0

I have a software A which has plugin B and C included as dll. Plugin B is using Newtonsoft V12 and Plugin C is using Newtonsoft V13. My Software A is using Newtonsoft V11. Currently it is so that my plugins bring the dlls in a subordinate. Software A has them in a parent folder. That means I have the dll 3 times in the project directory. But B and C use the dll from software A. If C has a function more by the newer version V13 I get as soon as my software A calls the new function in C an error because C uses the dll of A where the feature is not yet in it. How do I get each plugin (B and C) and the main software A to pick the appropriate Newtonsoft version dll. Can I do this automatically or tell each plugin once during init which one to use?

I use .Net6.0.

Thanks a lot!